# Splitting a network into subnets of multiple prefixes GitHub library

Tags: java, github, jar

I am new to GitHub and programming and I found a great library in GitHub with java classes and methods to help with splitting network into subnets. Here is the github link:
https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress
After downloading the source code and the .jar file, I ran `java -jar IPAddress.jar`

But I get this error -- > **no main manifest attribute, in IPAddress.jar**

can someone help me fix this problem?

BTW: the main reason I wanted this library was the following code example the library had:

```
adjustBlock("192.168.0.0/28", 2);
    
static void adjustBlock(String original, int bitShift) {
    IPAddress subnet = new IPAddressString(original).getAddress();
    IPAddress newSubnets = subnet.setPrefixLength(subnet.getPrefixLength() + 
        bitShift, false);
    TreeSet<IPAddress> subnetSet = new TreeSet<IPAddress>();
    Iterator<? extends IPAddress> iterator = newSubnets.prefixBlockIterator();
    iterator.forEachRemaining(subnetSet::add);

    PrintStream out = System.out;
    out.println("original block: " + subnet);
    out.println("prefix length increased by " + bitShift + ": " + newSubnets);
    out.println("subnets: " + subnetSet + "\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you run the JAR? This is a library which you can integrate it into your application by using the provided classes. However, as far as I can see, it is not a runnable application itself with a CLI or GUI.

Comment: I wanted to import JAR, into my code, and I read somewhere that you need to run the jar to import it. The problem might actually be that I didn't import properly, do you how to import the jar file into your .java code.

Comment: To use the classes and code in a jar, simply add the jar to your classpath.